# Is it possible that $a_n>0$ and $\sum a_n$ converges then $na_n \to 0$? (without assuming $a_n$ is decreasing)

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence

Can it be proven that : If $a_n>0$ and $\sum a_n$ converges then $na_n \to 0$ (without assuming $a_n$ is decreasing)

Please note This question does not require $a_n$ to be decreasing as condition, 
Is it possible to prove $na_n \to 0$ without requiring $a_n$ to be decreasing?
I keep thinking that $a_n>0$ and $\sum a_n$ converging then that implies that $a_n$ must be decreasing anyway(not monotonically decreasing necessarily )

Is it possible that $a_n>0$ and $\sum a_n$ converges then $na_n \not \to 0$?

There are already answered questions that assume $a_n$ to be decreasing as a requirement: (this question does not assume $a_n$ is decreasing)

[If $(a_n)$ is a decreasing sequence of strictly positive numbers and if $\sum{a_n}$ is convergent, show that $\lim{na_n}=0$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/369669/if-a-n-is-a-decreasing-sequence-of-strictly-positive-numbers-and-if-suma)

[Prove that if $\sum a_n$ converges, then $na_n \to 0$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1649465/prove-that-if-sum-a-n-converges-then-na-n-to-0)

[This](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2081722/does-a-sequence-have-these-properties) was the post that made me ask this question, a counter example of monotonoic decreasingness of $a_n$ was given in comments by the OP.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For example, try 
$$a_n = \cases{ 1/n & if $n$ is a power of $2$\cr                
                2^{-n} & otherwise} $$

Comment: How I can show that the series $\sum a_n$ is convergent ?

Comment: $\sum a_n=\sum 1/2^k+\sum_{n\neq 2^k} 1/2^n$.

Answer (score 2):

Let me add, also, the following example: define
$$a_n=\begin{cases}\dfrac{1}{n}, &\text{ if }  n=m^2 \text{ for some } m\in \mathbb N,\\
\dfrac{1}{n^2}, & \text{ otherwise.}
\end{cases}$$
Then $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}a_n$ converges, but $\lim\limits_{n\to+\infty}(n\cdot a_n)=0$ does not hold.