# If $\sum a_n$ converges where $a_n \ge 0 \; \forall \; n \in \Bbb N$, then $\{n a_n\}$ converges or diverges?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, proof-verification, examples-counterexamples

I was asked this question in a PhD interview. They didn't say whether $a_n$ is non-increasing or strictly decreasing. I tried various examples such as $a_n=\frac 1{n^p}$ where $p \gt 1$, $a_n=\frac 1{n^2 \ln n}$. Then $n a_n \to 0$.

I couldn't answer this question then.

But when I saw Robert Israel's answer to [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2084371/is-it-possible-that-a-n0-and-sum-a-n-converges-then-na-n-to-0-without) question, motivated from it, I defined a sequence $a_n$ as below :

$ a_n =
\begin{cases}
\frac 1n,  & \text{if $n$ is a power of 2} \\
0, & \text{otherwise.}
\end{cases}$

Here, $\sum a_n=\frac 12+ \frac 14+ \frac 18+ \cdots =\frac {\frac 12}{1 -\frac 12}=1$ and $\{n a_n\}$ diverges, because there are infinitely many terms of $0$ and $1$ in it. i.e.

$n a_n =
\begin{cases}
1,  & \text{if $n$ is a power of 2} \\
0, & \text{otherwise.}
\end{cases}$

So $\{na_n\}$ converges in some cases and diverges in some cases. Am I right?

**Note :** I have gone through these posts, [1](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4603/series-converges-implies-limn-a-n-0),[2](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/369669/if-a-n-is-a-decreasing-sequence-of-strictly-positive-numbers-and-if-suma?noredirect=1&lq=1), [3](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2084371/is-it-possible-that-a-n0-and-sum-a-n-converges-then-na-n-to-0-without) too but they have some extra conditions or specific details.

Thanks.

Comment: Makes sense to me.

Comment: Yes you are right (and posting a duplicate, for reasons hard to fathom).

Comment: Thanks for assuring me about my approach @Did and Jair Taylor. To Did, I respect your decision of making this post duplicate to the post whose answer motivated me. But I just want to state the differences between that post and mine : 1)My post has **proof verification** tag. I just wanted a feedback on my approach. Also that post doesn't have this tag. 2)(Minor difference) My post has $a_n \ge 0$ as a condition in the hypothesis but that post has condition in hypothesis as $a_n \gt 0$.

Comment: IOW, the answer of the question you are duplicating is proving *more* than you... More generally, it is rarely appropriate to post a new question to ask about very minor points of already posted answers. Comments are made for that, among other things.

Comment: @Did Okay I see. Next time I will keep this in mind.