Is it true that $\sum a_n$ converges $\implies \exists k\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $\forall n\ge k, ~a_n<\dfrac{1}{n}$?
If $\sum a_n$ converges, then $(a_n)\rightarrow 0$ and $a_n<\dfrac{1}{n}$ for infinitely many $n$.
But can we show that $\exists k\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $\forall n\ge k, ~a_n<\dfrac{1}{n}$ ?
If we want to show that the statement is false, we must find a sequence $(a_n)$ such that $\sum a_n$ converges and $a_n\ge \dfrac{1}{n}$, for infinitely many $n$.
If we add the condition that $(a_n)$ is non-negative, does it change the answer ?
Additionally, if $(a_n)$ is decreasing, then I believe the statement is true.
Proof: Since $(na_n)\rightarrow 0$, $\exists k\in \mathbb{N}$ such that, $\forall n\ge  k,$
$$|na_n|<1\implies a_n< \dfrac{1}{n}.$$
Note, $(a_n)$ must be a non-negative sequence in this case since $(a_n)$ is decreasing and $(a_n)\rightarrow 0$.

This is surely wrong. You can (for example) choose $a_n = 1/\sqrt n$ for infinitely many $n$ (and $a_n = 0$ otherwise) in a way that the series converges.

See for example here: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2084371/42969

It's only true if $(a_n)$ is nonnegative and decreasing.

@AdamRubinson
$P$ := $(a_n)$ is non-negative and decreasing.
$~~Q$ := $\sum a_n$ converges $\implies \exists k\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $\forall n\ge k, ~a_n<\dfrac{1}{n}.~~$
I know that $P\implies Q$, in other words, $P$ only if $Q$. You are saying that $Q$ only if $P$. I hope I got that right.

I mean that if $(a_n)$ is non-negative and decreasing then it is true, due to the argument you give in the question. But if $(a_n)$ is not decreasing or not non-negative, then isn't necessarily true.

@AdamRubinson Thank you. It is clear.

No (for the first question).
Set $$a_{n^2} = \frac{1}{n^2}. $$ Clearly we have $a_k \geq 1/k$ infinitely often. Then for non-square $k$ just set $a_k$ to be any other non-negative thing else that converges, even $a_k = 0$.
Part of the intuition here is that there are loads and loads of infinite sets $A \subset \mathbb{N}$ that are 'thin enough' for it to be the case that $$\sum_{n \in A} \frac{1}{n} < \infty.$$
